# Path reordering in SVG file > loose of CSS Definition in FireFox

Tags: javascript, svg, path, hover

stylesheet definitions:

```
path {
  fill: #CCCBCB;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

path:hover {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

The following code is working in Google Chrome, but not in FireFox and I do not know why?

I want to add a border color to a path of a more complex SVG file, at the moment it is hovered. So it got it work in Chrome but not in Firefox so far. Somehow I guess the event get's lost while reordering the pathes in an external SVG. Here is what i have done:

I'm just wondering why it works for Chrome and it doesn't in FireFox?

Any idea?

You can see the live test file here:
ixtract.de/Karten/test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ixtract.de/Karten/style_test.css">

 <div id="Map1">
  <object id="Map01" width="100%" data="http://ixtract.de/Karten/Test-01.svg" type="image/svg+xml">Your browser doesn't support SVG</object>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload= function () {loader();};

function loader(){
var mapSVG = 'Map01';
var a = document.getElementById(mapSVG);
var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
var myImage = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
 
for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseover', show);
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}

function show() {
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  this.addEventListener('mouseover', show); 
  this.addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}
function hide() {
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

[FireFox 51 result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq00T.png)

[Google Chrome result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrAWb.png)

Comment: That error usually means that you are not waiting for the SVG to load before trying to access it.  Make sure your code is inside a window.onload event handler.

Comment: @RobertLongson a complete example for an external SVG you will find in the code snipped. Here we go: Doesn't work even inside the window.onload: [SVG Test Link](http://ixtract.de/Karten/test.html)

Comment: It doesn't work in the code snippet, too, as the snippet doesn't resolve the external SVG and behaves like hovering over the path without reordering it! That's how it should look like, BUT with reordering the path...

Comment: @RobertLongson: Asking for a verifiable example but adding no comment on that? Strange...

Comment: @RobertLongson: If you ask me to prepare a example, i think you want to have a look at it, that's all. Great if you have better things to do! The code shows what's going on and you can take whatever SVG you want. FireFox won't handle it the right way thus without spending any error message...

Comment: @RobertLongson: As i wrote FireFox losses the css definiton of path:hover, which would color the shape in front with a red stroke. So it is actually not working. The aim is "I want to add a border color to a path of a more complex SVG file, at the moment it is hovered."

Comment: @RobertLongson: As i wrote it works in Safari and Google! The SVG grabs the same style.css and it works across documents this way. While I do not change the position of the path FireFox will work with the css sheet, too. Thanks for your help Robert, but it does not make sense if you do not read the problem or have a real look at the files.

Comment: @RobertLongson: but thanxs a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Moving elements around in the DOM breaks `:hover` rules in Firefox.  The hover rule won't be applied if you move the element you are hovering over.

The solution is to add a class to the hovered element and remove it when you leave the element.

```
function show() {
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  this.classList.add("hovered");
}
function hide() {
  this.classList.remove("hovered");
}
```

Then use that class to apply the hover styling.

```
path.hovered {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: I see... this way it turns out as a kind of workaround, but things get complicated this way. I tested it with Edge / IE and they get into trouble removing the class again.... but thanx a lot for your help

Comment: Sorry I forgot IE doesn't properly support `classList` on SVG elements. There are other ways to change the class though. Such as `this.setAttribute("class", "hovered");`.

Comment: As soon as i use `this.parentNode.appendChild(this);` Edge / IE they will loose the connection to the `addEventListener` and i do not get any hide function anymore.

Comment: You can always add it back again in your `show()` function.

Comment: Maybe it's possible, but i do not know how... It just doesn't work wit IE / Edge... Maybe you have some time next days and have a look at the Test: [MapTest]http://ixtract.de/Karten/Test-Map_toggle_9.html

Comment: If you try it in IE you will see you are getting at least one JS exception. That is probably part of your problem. Fix that and see if things improve.The exception is "Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference" at the line `if (attr.indexOf("hovered") == -1){`

Comment: This error only deals with the red bubbles, which had no class unfortunatelly, but i changed it and it does not interrupt with the wrong IE behavior. Thanx a lot for you help so far!

Comment: It's still throwing an error. Did you check it? The className property of SVG elements is not a string. So you can't use `indexOf()`.

Comment: I do not get any error in IE about the indexOf() anymore.

Comment: Your suggestion was exactly what I did: 'function show() {
  var myIDshow = this.id;   
  var attr = this.getAttribute("class");
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  if (this.className.baseVal.indexOf('hovered') == -1){
  this.className.baseVal =  attr+" hovered";
  }
  text.innerHTML = myIDshow;
  this.addEventListener('mouseover', show);
  this.addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}'

Comment: I can see at least one problem. `this.className.baseVal =  attr+" hovered"` shou;ld be `this.className.baseVal.value =  attr+" hovered"`. If you want any more help, please create a working [mcve] and post it in your question. Helping you debug a live version is unhelpful to future readers because when you fix it, this question will be mostly worthless.

Comment: Think it has to be ´this.className.baseVal´ as nothing else will work in no browser at all. So thanx for your help.